# Is it possible to have results still displayed upon return to a page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a filter table/(search) page, only when I navigate through some pages and return back to the filter table/(search) page in question the results disappear

I really don't want to reload the page. I simply want to return to the page and find that nothing has changed with the page. I simply want to return to the page as it was. As I see it if the keyword exists in the input box, then the results should still be displayed.

Please bear in mind that this is less of a search page though more a filter table results page

I could store the string in `localStorage`, but it does slow things down somewhat. There must be a simpler solution when considering that I'm only using a table filter for the results. Some kind of little trigger seems to make sense, but that's the problem I'm having difficulty with figuring

jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2 See this demo from another user has similarities to what I am doing, notice though when you navigate away from the the page and return the results are sill there! - this is what I'm aiming for

I wonder if anyone knows of simple plugin or some demo code that might be available. If someone could point me to this it would be fantastic!

```js
 
var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;
 
    $(document).ready(function init() {
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');
 
    table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
    rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');
 
    markInstance = new Mark(table);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
    });    
 
 
    function ContactsearchFX() {
      resetContent();
      markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
    }
 
 
 
    function resetContent() {
            $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
              //Remove this line to have a log of searches
 
             //noMatches.textContent = '';
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        $(row).removeClass('show');        
      });
    }
 
    function highlightMatches() {
      markInstance.mark(input.value, {
        each: showRow,
        noMatch: onNoMatches,
        exclude: ['.nonsearch']
      })
    }
 
 
 
    function showRow(element) {
    //alert(element);
      $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');                $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
                    //Parents incase of several nestings
    }
 
 
 
    function onNoMatches(text) {
      $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +     text +                '"</p>'); 
    }
    
    
    
    /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */
    
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
    /* on form submit find the trigger */
    if( $(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0 ){
        /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
     } 
     });    
    
        /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */
```

```css
 
.input-wrap  {
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
 
    #myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
      display: block;
    }
 
 
 
    #noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
      display: none;
    }
 
 
    .style1 tr {
      display: none;
    }
 
 
    .style1 .show {
      display: table-row;
    }
 
 
 
    #myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
    background: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    }
    mark {
    background: initial;
    }    .style1  {
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
    </script>
 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
    /mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrap">
    <label>
    Search 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required
       placeholder="Search Titles" />
    </label>
    </div>
 
    <div class="hintsWrap">
    <p id="noMatches"></p>
    <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
    </p>
    </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
                <tr>
                        <td>
    <br />
        <br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Type</th>
                                        <td>type1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Title</th>
                                        <td>title1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Description</th>
                                        <td>description1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Date</th>
                                        <td>date1</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Type</th>
                                        <td>type2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Title</th>
                                        <td>title2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Description</th>
                                        <td>description2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Date</th>
                                        <td>date2</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
    <br />
         <br />
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Type</th>
                                        <td>type3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Title</th>
                                        <td>title3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Description</th>
                                        <td>description3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">Date</th>
                                        <td>date3</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
                        </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please put a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in the question instead of behind a link.

Comment: Could you share your code

Comment: Done @Rilla - no problem

Answer (score 0):

its looks imposibble without to store somewhere, but i have a strange idea you could try.

this is the code, i added 2 new functions, one that change the url when you type in search box. (this couldnt work on jsfiddle so i upload an example to my domain so you can check if its work for you).
the second function get the url if exsist into the search box.

https://owtch.com/alltogether

[image]

```
<html>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrap">
    <label>
        Search
        <input onkeydown="inputchange(this)" id="myInput" type="text" required placeholder="Search Titles" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
    <p id="noMatches"></p>
    <p class="hints">
        Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
    </p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                                <td>type1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                                <td>title1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                                <td>description1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                                <td>date1</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</html>


<script>
    var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;

    $(document).ready(function init() {
        input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    var q = window.location.href.split("=");
    if(q[1]){
        input.value=q[1];
    }

        noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

        table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
        rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

        markInstance = new Mark(table);
        input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
    });


    function ContactsearchFX() {
        resetContent();
        markInstance.unmark({
            done: highlightMatches
        });
    }



    function resetContent() {
        $('.noMatchErrorText').remove();
        //Remove this line to have a log of searches

        //noMatches.textContent = '';
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            $(row).removeClass('show');
        });
    }

    function highlightMatches() {
        markInstance.mark(input.value, {
            each: showRow,
            noMatch: onNoMatches,
            exclude: ['.nonsearch']
        })
    }



    function showRow(element) {
        //alert(element);
        $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');
        $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings
    }



    function onNoMatches(text) {
        $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' + text + '"</p>');
    }



    /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */

    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        /* on form submit find the trigger */
        if ($(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0) {
            /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    function inputchange(x) {
        const addTourl = x.value;
        console.log("addTourl", addTourl);
        history.pushState("", "Title", "?q="+addTourl);
    }
</script>

<style>
    .input-wrap {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myInput:invalid~.hints {
        display: block;
    }



    #noMatches:empty,
    #noMatches:empty+.hints {
        display: none;
    }


    .style1 tr {
        display: none;
    }


    .style1 .show {
        display: table-row;
    }



    #myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
        background: orange;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
    }

    mark {
        background: initial;
    }

    .style1 {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

new version:

```
<html>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script 

    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <label>
            Search
            <input oninput="inputchange(this)" id="myInput" type="text" required placeholder="Search Titles" />
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hintsWrap">
        <p id="noMatches"></p>
        <p class="hints">
            Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
        </p>
    </div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                                <td>type1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                                <td>title1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                                <td>description1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                                <td>date1</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</html>


<script>
    var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;

    $(document).ready(function init() {
        input1 = document.getElementById('myInput');
   
        noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

        table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
        rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

        markInstance = new Mark(table);
        input1.addEventListener('input', ContactsearchFX, true);
        var q = window.location.href.split("=");
    if(q[1]){
        input1.value=q[1];
        const event = new MouseEvent('input', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  const cancelled = !input1.dispatchEvent(event);

    }

    });

    function ContactsearchFX() {
        resetContent();
        markInstance.unmark({
            done: highlightMatches
        });
    }



    function resetContent() {
        $('.noMatchErrorText').remove();
        //Remove this line to have a log of searches

        //noMatches.textContent = '';
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            $(row).removeClass('show');
        });
    }

    function highlightMatches() {
        markInstance.mark(input1.value, {
            each: showRow,
            noMatch: onNoMatches,
            exclude: ['.nonsearch']
        })
    }



    function showRow(element) {
        //alert(element);
        $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');
        $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings
    }



    function onNoMatches(text) {
        $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' + text + '"</p>');
    }



    /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */

    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        /* on form submit find the trigger */
        if ($(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0) {
            /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    function inputchange(x) {
        const addTourl = x.value;
        console.log("addTourl", addTourl);
        history.pushState("", "Title", "?q="+addTourl);
    }
</script>

<style>
    .input-wrap {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myInput:invalid~.hints {
        display: block;
    }



    #noMatches:empty,
    #noMatches:empty+.hints {
        display: none;
    }


    .style1 tr {
        display: none;
    }


    .style1 .show {
        display: table-row;
    }



    #myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
        background: orange;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
    }

    mark {
        background: initial;
    }

    .style1 {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: you should trigger somthing after you reload to see the result, i guess you know how to trigger typing?

Comment: No I don't know the the trigger typing part @Moti Salamon

Comment: i'll try to figure out

Comment: no im sorry, i can't solve this, there is something with "lodash" directory, so when you load with q=example, the table appear for 250 ms then disappear, maybee someone else could help with this directory.

Comment: Yes that would be great - it is a large part of the question description

Comment: Ok.. long time on that. this is little bit round.. but works.
https://owtch.com/fixforstack?q=type

i'll edit my answer and past the new code